# Industry name for Incongruities in a show

Tags: terminology, production-mistakes

I've never worked in TV on movie production and have never been on a set.

Is there an insider term for the incongruities: f-ups, timeline discrepancies, wrong character behavior, Starbucks coffee cup, and Canon mistakes?

I guess what I mean is that they happen all the time and it's a mood breaker.
Obviously, these things are watched for and fixed, but is there a word someone yells out, or just a general term for these?

Like "Hang on, that's a Gaff".

Comment: There isn't really a term used on set. Any scene takes 3 - 15 takes to get right, many of those for technical 'changes of mind' as much as actual 'error'. The public these days tend to call them 'bloopers' though I think that's a term we in the UK inherited from the States. See https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/106863/what-is-the-earliest-example-of-a-gag-reel Plot faults or cups in shot are generally considered 'continuity errors' or 'props fail'. [Props get blamed for everything, though ;)

Comment: Anecdotally… every time I'm watching a TV show or movie & there's a huge 'change of the scenery' in the shot; as the dust settles, I just call out "Cut. Reset. Props." It amuses my girlfriend, at least. I got her to join me on set during covid lockdown so she'd have a better understanding of what goes on.

Comment: In addition to what Tetsujin said, unless its a super controlled closed set where each take is technically perfect (and probably doesn't involve anything breathing..) - 95% of the takes will have an issue of some sort, its so common that there is no need for a word for it, everyone knows 'cut, reset, first positions please' etc, are the next words to hear. At the end of the day, everyone knows they have these scenes to get through, and everyone just really wants to get to hear the 'moving on' words that says you're done with this scene and can get one with the next (or its time for food..)

Comment: Thank you, everyone. These were great replies.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard **continuity errors** as well as simply **goofs**.